# Which hook is invoked when a user's roles are changed?

Tags: 6, users

I am trying to set a custom role expiration date in a subscription website using Ubercart and Paypal. Role expiration date is set by the role expiry module when a user completes payment.

I am trying to achieve this by using `hook_user()`. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: hook_user() is the way to go.

Comment: hook_user() seems to be the best solution for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any other hook to use, as it is evident from the code used from [`user_multiple_role_edit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_multiple_role_edit/6).

```
  // The role name is not necessary as user_save() will reload the user
  // object, but some modules' hook_user() may look at this first.
  $role_name = db_result(db_query('SELECT name FROM {role} WHERE rid = %d', $rid));

  switch ($operation) {
    case 'add_role':
      foreach ($accounts as $uid) {
        $account = user_load(array('uid' => (int) $uid));
        // Skip adding the role to the user if they already have it.
        if ($account !== FALSE && !isset($account->roles[$rid])) {
          $roles = $account->roles + array($rid => $role_name);
          user_save($account, array('roles' => $roles));
        }
      }
      break;
    case 'remove_role':
      foreach ($accounts as $uid) {
        $account = user_load(array('uid' => (int) $uid));
        // Skip removing the role from the user if they already don't have it.
        if ($account !== FALSE && isset($account->roles[$rid])) {
          $roles = array_diff($account->roles, array($rid => $role_name));
          user_save($account, array('roles' => $roles));
        }
      }
      break;
  }
```

The only invoked hooks are the ones used by [`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/6).